# Two divs height 100% responsive when decrease

Tags: css, html

I need a two column divs 100% of height, but responsive to page resizing (see the illustration below):

[image]

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: If the two column divs have a fixed width, you can put them in a container div that has width: 100%. Otherwise, one way you can do it is to use media queries for different break points.

Comment: 2 divs 50%
A side by side
height 100%

when the size is> = 400px is one on top of another ...

Comment: Try to follow SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and remember, you can edit your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/f2Uce/

The main part being the `@media (max-width:640px)`

Adjust the width of the bottom right box to see the change.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve such things by simply using `@media` queries:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
}

.one {
    background-color: #f00;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50%;
}

.two {
    background-color: #00f;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .content1,
    .content2 {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e7jRm/1/